# NSNotificationCenter - Observer Selector Being Called Twice

Tags: ios, swift, selector, nsnotificationcenter

I am creating a notification for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`, and for some reason the selector is being called twice. Here is my code in my `UIViewController`:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: “selectorHere”, name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

If I comment out the `addObserver` line in `viewWillAppear`, the notification isn't fired at all. I would assume this means that the above one line of code is the only place that I add an observer for the notification, but it's still getting called twice.

My main view controller is contained within a container view controller. I think that might be why my selector is being called twice, but I'm not sure.

I have tried all of the suggestions on the topics related to this issue but haven't found a solution that worked for me.

Any additional insight would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I am posting the notification in the AppDelegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive` method. Here is my code for that (Objective-C):

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}
```

This code is only firing once as well.

EDIT #2:

I am using the `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` methods because I am using a `UINavigationController`. I am adding and removing the observer to this notification on each view controller in the navigation stack. As far as I know, this would not work if I added the observer in `viewDidLoad`. If there is a better way to go about this, please let me know!

Comment: Try to add a breakpoint to check whether `viewWillAppear` is called twice.

Comment: @dasdom I've tried this, and `viewWillAppear` is only called once.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint or log something in `applicationDidBecomeActive` of the AppDelegate to check if this gets called twice?

Comment: Have you check it this also happens on device?

Comment: I set a breakpoint there as well, and `applicationDidBecomeActive` is only occuring once. Good idea for checking the device - yes it still happens on that as well. :/

Comment: Then it sounds like a bug to me. You should file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com/.

Comment: Oh, you post that yourself???? iOS is posting this already! Remove that code from `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Comment: See the edit of my answer.

Comment: @dasdom That did it! Please post an answer so I can give you credit! Thanks!!!

Comment: I add my observers in `viewDidLoad` and remove them in `deinit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...

Edit: Don't post that notification yourself. iOS posts this already.
[Read here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification)

Answer (score 0):

There can be a case when your view controller is appearing twice.
i.e. `viewWillAppear` is getting called twice.
Try adding observer in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I've tried this, and unfortunately the notification was still being called twice.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be doing that in the viewDidLoad, not viewWillAppear.  Also, viewWillAppear may be being called twice without it disappearing, giving you 2 observers. Unfortunately you do not have enough code here to give a strong answer.

edit:
I don't have enough rep to comment yet,  I would like to see where you are posting the notification,  that may be what is firing twice.

edit 2:
Yes, that notification is already being posted. by ios, you are duplicating the post.

Comment: This is all the code I have for this functionality aside from posting the notification in the app delegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive` method. Is there any code in particular you'd like to see?

Comment: I've edited my original post with information regarding where and how I am posting the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on -viewWillAppear:/-viewWillDisappear: for methods like these in my experience. There isn't always a good enough guarantee that they will be called once and when you expect them to be and that the calls will always be balanced. This is especially true if you are loading a view from a xib that contains multiple subViews. I might try moving the call to start observing into -viewDidLoad and remove the observer on -dealloc.